# How to read IF(AND()) from an excel in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to read this formula from excel :

```
   '=IF(AG>9,IF(AG>19,IF(AG>39,12%,8%),4%),0%)

 Following is the output I'm expecting, where AT contains the formula   
       AG   AT
       12   4%

     I'm using the following command:
        equation <- x[,"AT"] #x is the dataframe
        eq <- paste0("Cal1 <- with(y,",equation ,")")
        eval(parse(text = eq))
```

However on executing this, I'm getting an error: Error in parse(text = eq) : :1:61: unexpected ')'
1: Cal1 <- with(ds,ifelse(AF>9,ifelse(AF>19,ifelse(AF>39,12%,8%)
                                                                ^

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to port that Excel formula to R code? Or are you trying to design a program that automatically ports Excel to R?

Comment: I agree that this is quite unclear. If you are replacing `IF` by `ifelse`, then the operator `&` seems the closest match to the Excel function `AND`. `&` can be used as a prefix function (surround `&` by backticks) but I am skeptical that any `gsub` approach is robust enough to covert Excel formulas to equivalent R expressions.

Comment: I've read through some of your other questions - you won't receive any answers if you keep asking these kinds of questions. You should read through this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention `gsub`, I assume you're trying to directly port Excel formulas into R code.

In that case, you could **replace Excel's `AND` function with R's `ALL` function**. `ALL` will return `TRUE` provided that all logical arguments inside it evaluate to TRUE.

For example `ALL(3<4, 5>4, 12>10` evaluates to `TRUE` but `ALL(3<4, 5>4, 12>13` evalulates to `FALSE`.

*Note: The general form in R is to separate each logical statement with `&`, e.g. `3<4 & 5>4 & 12>10`. This would be possible but far more complex if your aim is to convert Excel formula directly, rather than rewrite it in R style.*

Comment: Thanks Mike!!! I'm trying to port this equation '=IF(AG>9,IF(AG>19,IF(AG>39,12%,8%),4%),0%) into R. I'm trying the following piece of code to execute this:                                                                                                                         eq <- paste0("Cal1 <- with(ds,",Str1,")")
      eval(parse(text = eq))

Comment: This throws error: Error in parse(text = eq) : <text>:1:61: unexpected ')'
1: Cal1 <- with(ds,ifelse(AF>9,ifelse(AF>19,ifelse(AF>39,12%,8%)^

Comment: Afraid I can't help further without more context, I was only addressing the immediate question of a direct substitute for AND(). Can you please edit your question to include your full R script that you're trying, including an example of the object that you're getting back from Excel (if it's not a string, you can use dput() to get to it directly)

Comment: The problem with `all` is that it isn't vectorized. For combining it with `ifelse` using `\`&\`` might be a better choice. Still, this might help them so +1